# Execute a stored procedure in SQL Server using http request

Tags: sql-server, http, stored-procedures

Is there a way to execute a stored procedure on an instance of SQL Server by using an http request? For example if my SQL Server is on a remote server with a specific IP address, can I do something like this:

```
http://[ipaddress]:[port]/database=[databaseName]/stored_procedure_name
```

to execute the procedure `stored_procedure_name` in database `[databaseName]` on the SQL Server instance with `[ipaddress]` running on `[port]`?

Comment: You'd have to have some kind of a (web) service / web application front end to get and handle the request - and that frontend would then call the SQL Server stored procedure. SQL Server *itself* doesn't have any HTTP endpoints / exposure (and that's a **good** thing!)

Comment: Ah ok ! I didn't know that it works like this. Thanks

Comment: Goodness!  I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of SQL Server supported native web services.  This was [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280436(v=sql.105).aspx%20[deprecated]) in `SQL Server 2008`  and eliminated in `SQL Server 2012`.  Microsoft recommends using WCF instead. Here is a  [discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5e75052-3a63-45c7-b234-f4d55dea8b67/reason-for-removing-native-xml-web-services-soaphttp-endpoints?forum=sqldenengine)  of the issue.